# Почему не работает команда обращения к .cmd файлу, который добавлен в path?

Tags: cmd, path

Я создал обычный скрипт hello.cmd который печатает текст. Добавил его в path (переменные среды пользователя), но при обращении к этому скрипту в консоли, ничего не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу в cmd название скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: где вы его добавили в Path? на картинке у вас создана переменная hello, в которой хранится путь к файлу. Про Path тут ничегошеньки нет.

Comment: и, к тому же, кириллица и пробелы в пути - не есть гуд.

Comment: Если чё - path это про папки, а не про файлы.